# Getting visit time from action time between two R data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to figure out what profile.views happened on what user visit. The users are uniquely identified by the pair uid,state. This data is stored in two data frames.

```
visits = data.frame(id=2001:2004, uid=c(1001,1002,1001,1001), state=c('CA','CA','CA','MA'), ts=c(51,52,53,54))
profile.views = data.frame(id=3001:3004, uid=c(1001,1003,1002,1001), state=c('CA','CA','CA','CA'), ts=c(51,57,59,59))

> visits
    id  uid state ts
1 2001 1001    CA 51
2 2002 1002    CA 52
3 2003 1001    CA 53
4 2004 1001    MA 54

> profile.views
id  uid state ts
1 3001 1001    CA 51
2 3002 1003    CA 57
3 3003 1002    CA 59
4 3004 1001    CA 59
```

For each profile.view, I want to figure out which visit it came from. This is done by looking back to the most recent visit with a matching uid and state that has a ts less than or equal to the ts on the profile.views row.

Here are the results I would want (in some form):

profile.views[1,] came from visits[1,]

profile.views[2,] did not come from any visit (this could be caused by a data recording error)

profile.views[3,] came from visits[2,]

profile.views[4,] came from visits[3,]

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster `data.table` way, which matches a profile view to a visit ID:

```
visits = data.frame(id=2001:2004, uid=c(1001,1002,1001,1001), state=c('CA','CA','CA','MA'), ts=c(51,52,53,54))
profile.views = data.frame(id=3001:3004, uid=c(1001,1003,1002,1001), state=c('CA','CA','CA','CA'), ts=c(51,57,59,59))
visits <- data.table(visits)
profile.views <- data.table(profile.views)
setkey(visits,uid,state,ts)
#orders columns so that joins are on first three columns
setcolorder(profile.views,c("uid","state","ts","id"))
##set names to avoid name collision
setnames(profile.views,c("uid","state","view.ts","view.id"))
##rolling join
visits[profile.views,roll=TRUE]
    # uid state ts   id view.id
# 1: 1001    CA 51 2001    3001
# 2: 1003    CA 57   NA    3002
# 3: 1002    CA 59 2002    3003
# 4: 1001    CA 59 2003    3004
```

Comment: +1 but the `setcolorder` and `setnames` aren't needed :)  Easier and faster to key `i` too:  `setkey(profile.views,uid,state,ts)`.

Comment: That was my first guess, but I got an error I don't understand: ``Error in `[.data.table`(visits, profile.views, roll = TRUE) : 
  Attempting roll join on factor column i.state. Only integer, double or character colums may be roll joined.`` I'm running R 2.15.2 and data.table 1.8.6.

Comment: That means that either state is the last column of i's key, or x's key has 2 columns not 3. Something like that. Iiuc this case, then both tables should have a 3 column key and the last key column should be ts in both.

Comment: I have both tables keyed by the same three columns `uid,state,ts`, but `roll` appears to be ignoring how `profile.views` is keyed and looking just at the third column `state`. Possibly an error-check gone awry? The roll appears to work fine if I key just by `uid` and `ts`, or by `state` and `ts`.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped then. Something reproducible please and i'll take a look.

Comment: Oh dear, yes it's an error check gone awry. Will fix, apologies. Whenever the key columns are out of order and a non last join column is a factor. In the meantime could change from factor to character: `profile.views[,state:=as.character(state)]`, `visits[,state:=as.character(state)]` too, before setting the keys again.  Bug filed [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2450&group_id=240&atid=975). Thanks!

Comment: Whew, I'm not going crazy. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Great answer and discussion! I will use this way.

Comment: In trying to learn more about R and build my intuition about how to solve things, I am interested to know if there is a way to do this without data.table. Is it that there is no way to do this without upgrading the data.frames into data.tables or just that the data.table way is much faster?

Comment: @dubois The `data.table` way is meant to be faster both computationally and intuitively with the commands. I can think of a way to do this in base R using `merge` and `aggregate`, using the same method as the `sqldf` example.

Comment: Bug fixed and test added now in 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL-style syntax with `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("
SELECT a.id, a.uid, a.state, a.ts, MAX(b.ts) AS visit_ts
FROM \"profile.views\" AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN visits AS b
ON a.uid = b.uid
AND a.state = b.state
AND a.ts >= b.ts
GROUP BY a.id, a.uid, a.state, a.ts
ORDER BY a.id
")
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this sqldf package!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution. There are a few things that can probably be done better, but here's a first pass at it.

```
library(data.table)
visits <- data.table(visits)
profile.views <- data.table(profile.views)
##renames some columns to avoid name collision
##there's probably a better solution to this
setnames(profile.views,c("id","ts"),c("view.id","view.ts"))
setkey(visits,uid,state)
setkey(profile.views,uid,state)
##outer joins visits to profile.views by uid and state
##leaving NA if a row in profile.views has no matches
#visits[profile.views] 
##filters out rows where views happen before visits
#visits[profile.views][view.ts >= ts | is.na(ts)] 
##picks the latest visit timestamp by view
visits[profile.views][view.ts >= ts | is.na(ts), 
  list(visit.ts=max(ts)), 
  by=list(view.id,uid,state,view.ts)][order(view.id)]
#    view.id  uid state view.ts visit.ts
# 1:    3001 1001    CA      51       51
# 2:    3002 1003    CA      57       NA
# 3:    3003 1002    CA      59       52
# 4:    3004 1001    CA      59       53
```

Comment: +1 but this is what 'roll=TRUE' is for, a major feature of data.table that is much faster than SQL.

Comment: Ah, shucks. I'll have another go at it.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R's `merge` and `aggregate`:

```
visits = data.frame(id=2001:2004, uid=c(1001,1002,1001,1001), state=c('CA','CA','CA','MA'), ts=c(51,52,53,54))
profile.views = data.frame(id=3001:3004, uid=c(1001,1003,1002,1001), state=c('CA','CA','CA','CA'), ts=c(51,57,59,59))
##merges data frames based on uid and state
newdf.merged <- merge(visits,profile.views, by=c("uid","state"),all.y=TRUE)
##puts unmatched rows into another dataset
newdf.na <- with(newdf,newdf[is.na(ts.x),])
##filters views that happened after visits (like WHERE)
newdf.filter <- with(newdf,newdf[ts.y >= ts.x,])
##aggregates using the max function, selecting max id and ts
newdf.agg <- aggregate(cbind(id.y,ts.y) ~ uid + state + id.x + ts.x, data = newdf.filter, FUN = max)
##merges aggregated result and na rows
newdf.final <- rbind(newdf.agg,newdf.na)
##optional ordering step
newdf.final <- newdf.final[with(newdf.final,order(uid,state,id.x)),]
```